# How to include Lua module in build

Tags: module, lua

I downloaded [this](https://github.com/Neopallium/nixio/) Lua module and installed it with make. However, when I try to use it in my code, I get the following error:

```
VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ lua socket_test.lua 
lua: socket_test.lua:1: module 'nixio.util' not found:
    no field package.preload['nixio.util']
    no file './nixio/util.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nixio/util.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nixio/util/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/nixio/util.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/nixio/util/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/nixio/util.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/nixio/util/init.lua'
    no file './nixio/util.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/nixio/util.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/nixio/util.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/nixio/util.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
    no file './nixio.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/nixio.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/nixio.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/nixio.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    socket_test.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

And the first line of my code:

```
local nixio = require "nixio", require "nixio.util"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is `nixio` installed?

Comment: I think it just compiled all the source files in the directory it came in

Comment: actually it created a directory called `dist/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nixio` with the files `fs.lua` and `util.lua` and it also created `/dist/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/nixio.so`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see these options:

1. Try `make install` and hope that it works. Perhaps set some variable such as `PREFIX` nothing.
2. Manually move `dist/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nixio` to `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/nixio` and `dist/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/nixio.so` to `/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/nixio.so`.
3. Add the `dist` paths to the environment: `LUA_CPATH='dist/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;;'` and `LUA_PATH='dist/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;;'`.
4. Add the `dist` paths in Lua: `package.cpath='dist/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;'..package.cpath` and `package.path='dist/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;'..package.path`.

Comment: Got it working! When I tried doing `make install`, I had to manually create the directories `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1` and `/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1`. Then I called `sudo apt-get remove lua5.2` which appeared to remove my lua5.2 but left a 5.1 install which seems to have worked.

Comment: @ihf,Tom i have done all the steps mentioned,but i have a doubt in step 4,at which lua file should we perform step 4?